# access to element in parent div with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to access all function just do in a div ! 
for Example :

```
<div class="ow_chat_dialog" id="main_tab_contact_11">
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
<button onclick="sersrc()"></button>
</div>

<div class="ow_chat_dialog" id="main_tab_contact_12">
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
<button onclick="sersrc()"></button>
</div>

<div class="ow_chat_dialog" id="main_tab_contact_13">
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
<button onclick="sersrc()"></button>
</div>
14
15
16
.
.
....
<script>
function setscr(){
document.findviewbyid("myframe").src="hrl..."
}
</script>
```

in this code i can create some div with one class name and id...
But when i click on any button the first iframe change ! 
if i want just change the sibling iframe !
** just use javaScript , Not Jquery .

Comment: invalid html, duplicate id `myframe`

Comment: So , how i can solve it ? this div create by user ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ids, they must be unique. Use classes instead:

```
<div class="ow_chat_dialog" class="main_tab_contact_13">
    <iframe class="myframe"></iframe>
    <button onclick="sersrc(this)"></button>
</div>
```

Then let `sersrc` know which button was clicked by passing button reference. From there you can find sibling iframe like this for example:

```
function setscr(obj) {
    obj.parentNode.querySelector(".myframe").src = "hrl..."
}
```

If you are sure that iframe is going to be always immediately before the button then you can simply do

```
obj.previousElementSibling.src = "hrl..."
```

(course this is less reliable since depends on structure).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Comment: Did you pass `this` reference: `onclick="sersrc(this)"` ?

Comment: i use this : var frame = this.parentNode.querySelector(".myframe"); frame.contentWindow.location.href = 'localhost:8585/demos/project/index.html';;

Comment: You should use `obj.parentNode`, because `this` is not button, but global object `window`.

Comment: agane Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: Make sure you changed `id="myframe"` to `class="myframe"`. And it will work http://jsfiddle.net/fn928v27/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66316/discussion-between-user3787191-and-dfsq).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.ow_chat_dialog > button');
function handler () {
  this.previousElementSibling.src = "//stackoverflow.com";
}
for (var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
  els[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
```

```html
<div class="ow_chat_dialog">
  <iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
  <button></button>
</div>
<div class="ow_chat_dialog">
  <iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
  <button></button>
</div>
<div class="ow_chat_dialog">
  <iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: how i can use ur code in a function ? if it is Further what ? dose we have previousElementSibling in javaScript ?

Comment: if i chage iframe and button ! first button and then iframe can i use ur code ? i want use ur javaScript code in button onclick !

Comment: Avoid inline event listeners. Just write the code you want to run at on click in `handler` function.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Comment: You are doing something wrong. `this.previousElementSibling` can't never be `undefined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66314/discussion-between-user3787191-and-oriol).